# Giving Access denied for user 'SELECT * FROM users', but it's not a user

Tags: php

I have a problem that i can't fix by myself. The error is this:

`mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'SELECT * FROM users'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in D:\xampp\htdocs\php\FUNCTIONS\UPDATE\update1.php on line 9`

The fact is that `SELECT * FROM users` is a query.

connection.php:

```
<?php

global $connection;

if ( isset( $_POST["submit"] ) ) {

    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","loginapp");

    if ( !$connection ) {
        die( "Query has failed!" . "<br/>" . mysqli_error( $connection ) );
    }
}
?>
```

update1.php:

```
<?php
include 'D:\xampp\htdocs\php\FUNCTIONS\connect.php';
?>

<?php


$query1 = 'SELECT * FROM users';
$result = mysqli_connect( $connection, $query1 );

if ( !$result ) {
    die( 'Query has failed!' . '<br/>' . mysqli_error( $connection ) );
}
?>
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried to change database and the error did go away. But the problem now is the connection variable. So i'm gonna delete the `connect.php` and i will include the content of the file in every file that need to connect (but not create data ) to the database.

Comment: `$result = mysqli_connect( $connection, $query1 );` -> you should use `mysqli_query()` function here

Answer (score 0):

1. In your `update1.php` , you included the `connect.php`, please check if you have the correct file name.
2. Check if you have the correct password for the db config.
3. Looks like your query is correct so its probably a problem with your db config, check if the db password for the user - `root` is correct. You might have changed it.

Comment: I didn't set a password, because i'm the only one "working" on this project. I have XAMPP. So i think it's the db. I'll try to make another one

Answer (score 0):

To make a query, you use `mysqli_query` instead of `mysqli_connect`.

In `update1.php`:

```
//...
$result = mysqli_query( $connection, $query1 );
```

- More info [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)